# Sorgenfreyline proof or disproof

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

$(\Bbb{R},\tau)$ is Sorgenfrey topological space, also known as lower limit topology, $x \in \Bbb{R}$ and $\mathscr{N}(x)$ shows all neighboorhoods of $x$. Prove or disprove $$\bigcap_{U \in \mathscr{N(x)}}\overline{U}=\{x\}$$

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pick $y \in \cap  \bar{U}$ such that $y \neq x$. Since this topology is Haudorff, we can have the disjoint open set of $x$ and $y$ respectively, contradicts with the choice of $y$.

Hope this helps.